# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' Unknown layout attribute'

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

I am trying to give **vertical space constraint** programatically for Admob native ads compenents by using **NSLayoutConstraint**.

I assigned nativeAdView in the **ListTileNativeAdFactory** class.

(I used this guide : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#7)

```
let nativeAdView = nibView as! GADNativeAdView
```

In fact I can give **height constraint** without a problem.

This code **works without a problem**:(It gives **height constraint** to nativeAdView.mediaView)

```
   if let mediaView = nativeAdView.mediaView{
        NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: mediaView,
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 120).isActive = true
        }
```

On the other hand, If I try to give **vertical space constraint(top)** with this code:

```
   if let mediaView = nativeAdView.mediaView, let calltoActionView = nativeAdView.callToActionView{
            NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: mediaView,
                attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top,
                relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
                toItem: calltoActionView,
                attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 15).isActive = true
            }
```

It gives **Unknown layout attribute** error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for
> <GADMediaView: 0x11c0552e0; frame = (35 369.5; 250 150); autoresize =
> RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x2801e2f00>>: Unknown layout attribute'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I'm using Google's official NativeAdView file.

[github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/blob/master/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/ios/Runner/NativeAdView.xib](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/blob/master/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/ios/Runner/NativeAdView.xib)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute,` => `attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top,`

Comment: In other words, in the first one, you set height, and it doesn't depend on another one, just on a constant. On the second one, you set the top, says it needs to be equals to `callActionView`, but it could be equal to bottom, top, leading, trailing value. So you need to set something else thatn `.nontAnAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try it.

Comment: @Larme Thank you very much!!! You saved my day!! Your solution is working...